# Chrome Devtools ACTUAL data size/transferred

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

On the Network Tab of the Chrome Devtools I cannot understand the difference between the 2 data values reported (`850KB / 14.7 MB transferred`). I assume the first value `850KB` is data size and the second value `14.7 MB` the transferred data. However I am confused.

1. What is the actual size of the files?
2. Shouldn't the size of the files equal the size of the transferred values or shouldn't the transferred size (I assume `14.7 MB`) be smaller than the actual size of the files (in case the files were compressed)?

[image]

The [chrome devtools page on resource loading measurements](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/network-performance/resource-loading) report only one value; so I am confused.

Comment: The first one is for [selected](https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/third_party/WebKit/Source/devtools/front_end/network/NetworkLogView.js?l=749&rcl=9c2daf8b0097f103e8028dc537ecbca2726496e2) (shown by the filter) requests.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Chrome inspect gives u a bunch of filters such as All,XHR , JS , img. So the amount is for the filtered part of ur data. If you select "All" option in the filter you will find something like 14.7MB/14.7MB

Comment: In Chrome 74 there can still last the difference between *transferred* (e.g. 3.2 kb) and *resources* (e.g. 2.5 kb) with filter **all**. One source of the difference might be caching, but I don't know much about the details, another are [cookies and other web site data](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/121792).

Answer (score 3):

On top, you can see the size of the file transferred over the network (which may be compressed by your server).

The uncompressed size of the file is displayed in gray just below.

Official documentation here: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/network/reference#uncompressed